# How to make a filtered clone of a three.js scene?

Tags: three.js

I need to make a copy of a three.js scene, filtering out some of the geometry. I'd like to do this in a memory-efficient way, so I'd like to share the (large) meshes.

I'm thinking to recurse through the scene, copying objects from source to dest (or skipping them), and when I get to a mesh, adding a reference somehow rather than copying it.

Is that possible? Any sample code available?

Comment: I'm not sure this helps but working with [Object3D.traverse()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.traverse) might be a good start. If you call it on the scene object, you can process all objects in the scene graph with the applied callback function. Simple [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tqu2va0p/).

Comment: Thanks; that's useful -- my main concern is whether it's legit (and even possible) to reference a mesh from two different scenes.

Comment: No, that does not work. All classes derived from `Object3D` have exactly one parent. A `Scene` itself is also derived from `Object3D`, so its descendants can only be part of a single scene graph.

Comment: Thanks, that's a bit unfortunate but understandable. I do see the GLTFExporter playing a trick where it pushes things onto `object.children` in a (very) temporary scene (rather than using `.add` which unlinks from the old parent), but that seemed dangerous to me.